# Using NHibernate JoinAlias returning less rows compared to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate

While converting an EF query over to NHibernate came across a problem where using JoinAlias is returning less rows.

```
//Something like this cannot be used in NHibernate
x.UserEntity.type_id == typeId1
```

Below are both the queries

```
//Entity Framework
dbContext.Seeker.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.posting_id == postingId
            && (x.source_id == sourceId1 || x.source_id == sourceId2)
            && x.status_id != statusId1 &&
                (x.status_id == statusId2 || x.status_id == statusId3 ||
                x.status_id == statusId4 || x.status_id == statusId5 ||
                x.status_id == statusId6 || x.status_id == statusId7 ||
                x.status_id == statusId8 || x.status_id == statusId9)
            && (x.UserEntity.type_id == typeId1 || x.UserEntity.type_id == typeId2)
            && (x.rating == rating1
                || (x.rating >= rating2 && x.rating < rating3)
                || (x.rating >= rating4 && x.rating < rating5)
                || (x.rating >= rating6 && x.rating < rating7)
                || (x.rating >= rating8 && x.rating < rating9)
                || x.rating == rating10));

//NHibernate
(db.QueryOver<Seeker>()
    .Where(x => x.posting_id == postingId
    && (x.source_id == sourceId1 || x.source_id == sourceId2)
    && x.status_id != statusId1 &&
                (x.status_id == statusId2 || x.status_id == statusId3 ||
                x.status_id == statusId4 || x.status_id == statusId5 ||
                x.status_id == statusId6 || x.status_id == statusId7 ||
                x.status_id == statusId8 || x.status_id == statusId9)
    && (x.rating == rating1
        || (x.rating >= rating2 && x.rating < rating3)
        || (x.rating >= rating4 && x.rating < rating5)
        || (x.rating >= rating6 && x.rating < rating7)
        || (x.rating >= rating8 && x.rating < rating9)
        || x.rating == rating10))
    .JoinAlias(ue => ue.UserEntity, () => u).Where(() => u.type_id == typeId1 || u.type_id == typeId2));
```

Any clues on what needs to modified on the NHibernate query?

Comment: Did you compare the SQL generated by each query? This will help you identify what the difference between the two is.

Answer (score 1):

Look at 'Query' instead of 'QueryOver'. Query supports almost everything from standard Linq.